# Prove $ \frac{a}{5b+c^3}+\frac{b}{5c+a^3}+\frac{c}{5a+b^3} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $a + b + c = 3; a, b, c \ge 0$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers, no two of which are zero such that $a+b+c=3.$ Prove that
> $$ \dfrac{a}{5b+c^3}+\dfrac{b}{5c+a^3}+\dfrac{c}{5a+b^3} \geq \dfrac{1}{2}.$$

I think this inequality must use the *Cauchy-Schwarz* inequality
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{a(5b+c^3)}\sum_{cyc} a(5b+c^3)\ge (a+b+c)^2=9$$

then it suffices to prove that
$$\dfrac{9}{5(ab+bc+ac)+(ac^3+ba^3+cb^3)}\ge \dfrac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: [Please see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown. Note that the correct way to produce *italics* is `*italics*`.

Comment: I think SOS can kill this, but it won't be very nice.

Comment: can you share your $SOS$ methods? Thank you ,@nikoma

Comment: See this [link(PDF)](https://321da88a-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/imocanada/2009-summer-camp/2009SummerCamp-DavidArthur-SumofSquares.pdf)

Comment: The last inequality doesn't hold for $a\simeq 1.953062$, $b=3-a$ and $c=0$.

Answer (score 3):

This is very ugly proof, but it's a proof. First we homogenize the inequality and then because of the cyclicity it suffices to consider two cases.

1) We have $a \leq b \leq c$, then there exist $u,v \geq 0$ such that $b = a + u$, $c = a + u + v$, then the inequality can be expanded into $$24300 a^7 (u^2 + u v + v^2) + 
 27 a^6 (3916 u^3 + 8007 u^2 v + 8859 u v^2 + 2384 v^3) + (2 u + 
    v)^2 (29 u^3 + 47 u^2 v + 32 u v^2 + 9 v^3) (13 u^4 + 75 u^3 v + 
    130 u^2 v^2 + 60 u v^3 + 10 v^4) + 
 27 a^5 (7609 u^4 + 23750 u^3 v + 33585 u^2 v^2 + 17444 u v^3 + 
    3013 v^4) + 
 9 a^4 (25502 u^5 + 107036 u^4 v + 189674 u^3 v^2 + 145480 u^2 v^3 + 
    51166 u v^4 + 6913 v^5) + 
 a^3 (157534 u^6 + 828219 u^5 v + 1780485 u^4 v^2 + 1807807 u^3 v^3 + 
    962376 u^2 v^4 + 264369 u v^5 + 29752 v^6) + 
 a (2 u + v) (7620 u^7 + 52167 u^6 v + 138412 u^5 v^2 + 
    180418 u^4 v^3 + 133318 u^3 v^4 + 57590 u^2 v^5 + 13535 u v^6 + 
    1355 v^7) + 
 a^2 (65669 u^7 + 413968 u^6 v + 1051107 u^5 v^2 + 1329962 u^4 v^3 + 
    949111 u^3 v^4 + 394122 u^2 v^5 + 89315 u v^6 + 8575 v^7) \geq 0$$ which is obvious.

2) We have $a \leq c \leq b$, then there exist $u,v \geq 0$ such that $b = a + u + v$, $c = a + u$, again expanding the inequality it becomes $$24300 a^7 (u^2 + u v + v^2) + 
 27 a^6 (3916 u^3 + 3741 u^2 v + 4593 u v^2 + 2384 v^3) + (2 u + 
    v)^2 (29 u^3 + 40 u^2 v + 25 u v^2 + 5 v^3) (13 u^4 - 23 u^3 v - 
    17 u^2 v^2 + 27 u v^3 + 18 v^4) + 
 27 a^5 (7609 u^4 + 6686 u^3 v + 7989 u^2 v^2 + 8912 u v^3 + 
    3013 v^4) + 
 9 a^4 (25502 u^5 + 20474 u^4 v + 16550 u^3 v^2 + 36346 u^2 v^3 + 
    28594 u v^4 + 6913 v^5) + 
 a^3 (157534 u^6 + 116985 u^5 v + 2400 u^4 v^2 + 182623 u^3 v^3 + 
    302685 u^2 v^4 + 163011 u v^5 + 29752 v^6) + 
 a (2 u + v) (7620 u^7 + 1173 u^6 v - 14570 u^5 v^2 - 4163 u^4 v^3 + 
    19126 u^3 v^4 + 21491 u^2 v^5 + 9035 u v^6 + 1355 v^7) + 
 a^2 (65669 u^7 + 45715 u^6 v - 53652 u^5 v^2 + 14468 u^4 v^3 + 
    159388 u^3 v^4 + 154038 u^2 v^5 + 59966 u v^6 + 8575 v^7)$$ where the inequalities $$13 u^4 - 23 u^3 v - 17 u^2 v^2 + 27 u v^3 + 18 v^4 \geq 0$$ $$7620 u^7 + 1173 u^6 v - 14570 u^5 v^2 - 4163 u^4 v^3 + 
 19126 u^3 v^4 + 21491 u^2 v^5 + 9035 u v^6 + 1355 v^7 \geq 0$$ $$65669 u^7 + 45715 u^6 v - 53652 u^5 v^2 + 14468 u^4 v^3 + 
 159388 u^3 v^4 + 154038 u^2 v^5 + 59966 u v^6 + 8575 v^7 \geq 0$$ are true and easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{a}{5b+c^3}+\frac{b}{5c+a^3}+\frac{c}{5a+b^3}
\ge \frac{[a(3a + c) + b(3b + a) + c(3c + b)]^2}{\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(3a + c)^2(5b + c^3)}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{[a(3a + c) + b(3b + a) + c(3c + b)]^2}{\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(3a + c)^2(5b + c^3)} \ge \frac{1}{2}. \tag{1}$$

We can use BW (Buffalo Way) to prove (1). *Note*: @nikoma's proof is BW.

After homogenization, clearing the denominator, we need to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &18\,{a}^{6}-6\,{a}^{5}b+48\,{a}^{5}c-64\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}-25\,{a}^{4}bc+
 80\,{a}^{4}{c}^{2}-26\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}-35\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}c\\
 &\quad +10\,{a}^{3}b
 {c}^{2}-26\,{a}^{3}{c}^{3}+80\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}+10\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}c-35\,
 {a}^{2}b{c}^{3}-64\,{a}^{2}{c}^{4}+48\,a{b}^{5}\\
 &\quad-25\,a{b}^{4}c-35\,a{b}
 ^{3}{c}^{2}+10\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{3}-25\,ab{c}^{4}-6\,a{c}^{5}+18\,{b}^{6}-
 6\,{b}^{5}c-64\,{b}^{4}{c}^{2}\\
 &\quad-26\,{b}^{3}{c}^{3}+80\,{b}^{2}{c}^{4}+
 48\,b{c}^{5}+18\,{c}^{6} \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Denote LHS by $f(a, b, c)$.

Since the inequality is cyclic, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $c \le a \le b$

Let $a = c + s$ and $b = c + s + t$ for $s, t\ge 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 f(a, b, c) &=  \left( 396\,{s}^{2}+396\,st+396\,{t}^{2} \right) {c}^{4}+ \left( 917
 \,{s}^{3}+2244\,{s}^{2}t+2661\,s{t}^{2}+667\,{t}^{3} \right) {c}^{3}\\
 &\quad +
 \left( 846\,{s}^{4}+3429\,{s}^{3}t+5394\,{s}^{2}{t}^{2}+2811\,s{t}^{3
 }+471\,{t}^{4} \right) {c}^{2}\\
&\quad + \left( 375\,{s}^{5}+2085\,{s}^{4}t+
 4137\,{s}^{3}{t}^{2}+3252\,{s}^{2}{t}^{3}+1125\,s{t}^{4}+150\,{t}^{5}
 \right) c \\
 &\quad +68\,{s}^{6}+456\,{s}^{5}t+1088\,{s}^{4}{t}^{2}+1134\,{s}^{3
 }{t}^{3}+590\,{s}^{2}{t}^{4}+156\,s{t}^{5}+18\,{t}^{6}.
\end{align*}
Since the coefficients are non-negative, we have $f(a, b, c) \ge 0$.

**Case 2**: $c \le b \le a$

Let $b = c + s$ and $a = c + s + t$ for $s, t\ge 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 f(a, b, c) &=  \left( 396\,{s}^{2}+396\,st+396\,{t}^{2} \right) {c}^{4}+ \left( 917
 \,{s}^{3}+507\,{s}^{2}t+924\,s{t}^{2}+667\,{t}^{3} \right) {c}^{3}\\
 &\quad +
 \left( 846\,{s}^{4}-45\,{s}^{3}t+183\,{s}^{2}{t}^{2}+1074\,s{t}^{3}+
 471\,{t}^{4} \right) {c}^{2} \\
 &\quad + \left( 375\,{s}^{5}-210\,{s}^{4}t-453\,{
  s}^{3}{t}^{2}+399\,{s}^{2}{t}^{3}+567\,s{t}^{4}+150\,{t}^{5} \right) c\\
 &\quad +68\,{s}^{6}-48\,{s}^{5}t-172\,{s}^{4}{t}^{2}+18\,{s}^{3}{t}^{3}+176\,
 {s}^{2}{t}^{4}+102\,s{t}^{5}+18\,{t}^{6}.
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to prove that the coefficients of $c^2, c, c^0$ are all non-negative. Thus, $f(a, b, c) \ge 0$.

We are done.