# Neat Inequalities that is hard to solve

Tags: inequality

**if** $a,b,c>0$ **and** $a+b+c=3$ **then prove that**

$$\frac{a}{5b+c^3}+\frac{b}{5c+a^3}+\frac{c}{5a+b^3} \ge\frac{1}{2}$$

I've already searched this on the internet I already found the solution but the author of this problem said it can be done without using uvw which is very long if u have a solution it will be great without using uvw thanks

Comment: What do you mean by uvw?

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/the-uvw-method/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453488/42969, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1644355p10371329